# Algebraic numbers with special properties

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-extensions

There is a "result" which would help me in my research.

**Lemma.** *Let $d$ and $n$ be positive integers and let $\alpha$ be a real algebraic number with degree $r$. Then, there exists a real algebraic number $\gamma$, with degree $n$, for which $\alpha+\gamma^d$ has degree $nr$.*

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just take $\gamma = 1+p^{1/n}$ with $p$ a large enough prime number

Comment: @reuns Is the proof of this fact elementary? Or it needs some deeper results (like discriminant of number fields etc)? Thanks Reuns.

Comment: @reuns Any hint how to prove it, please?